# Checksum in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Do we have similar kind of checksum function (SQL) in oracle function. I would to store it in a table and use key/value for update statements. One of my current process contains 15 columns, need to check any change is there between source and destination, instead of checking one by one column whether change is happened or not, would like to have single column in table to helps whether change happened in 15 columns

Comment: Apply a hash function to each column; then concatenate the hashes (with delimiters), and perhaps apply the hash function again to the result. You may run into problems if you have CLOB functions, or nested tables, etc.

Comment: Do you mean ORA_HASH?. I saw in one of article this column need to update once data ported in table. but is there any way has function values auto populates in table while loading data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Databases are good at keeping track of changes, that's what they are for.

Maybe the built-in `ORA_ROWSCN` is good enough for your change tracking? By default it tracks only the changes per block, but you can enable a table to track the change for each row with the - oddly named - clause `ROWDEPENDENCIES`:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
 a NUMBER, 
 b NUMBER, 
 c NUMBER
) ROWDEPENDENCIES;


INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2,2,2);
SELECT current_scn FROM v$database;
2380496
```

After a while:

```
UPDATE t SET b=20, c=20 WHERE a=2;
SELECT current_scn FROM v$database;
2380665
```

Now you can query the system change number SCN each row was changed:

```
SELECT ORA_ROWSCN AS scn, a,b,c FROM t;
SCN       A    B    C    
2380496   1    1    1
2380665   2   20   20
```

For the last 5 days, Oracle can translate a SCN to approximate real time (in Oracle 10 ± 5 minutes, from Oracle 11 ± 3 seconds):

```
SELECT ORA_ROWSCN AS SCN, SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) AS ts, a,b,c FROM t;
SCN       TS                    A    B    C    
2380496   2020-05-15 20:20:38   1    1    1
2380665   2020-05-15 20:23:06   2   20   20
```

It's documented in Oracles [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF50953).

Comment: Unfortunately, ORA_ROWSCN is not 100% reliable, even with ROWDEPENDENCIES. This sentence in the document is the problem: "If a block is queried twice, then it is possible for the value of ORA_ROWSCN to change between the queries even though rows have not been updated in the time between the queries". ORA_ROWSCN is (usually) good enough for applications using optimistic locking, but it can't be trusted 100%. Which is frustrating, because it seems like Oracle must use the SCN for comparisons internally.